# Limit on launch arguments characters for iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to pass images to UI Tests. To do this I use launch arguments.

```
let bundle = NSBundle (forClass: self.dynamicType)
let images = ["img1", "img2"]
    .map {
        bundle.URLForResource($0, withExtension: "jpg")!
    }
    .map {
        NSData(contentsOfURL: $0)!
    }
    .map {
        $0.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: .allZeros))
    }

XCUIApplication().launchArguments= ["IMAGES", images.joinWithSeparator("_")]
```

I unpack them the same way. A one or two small images work as expected, but if I use large pictures I get:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)

Is there some arbitrary number of characters I can pass as the launch arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal can tell you the maximum length of the command line:

```
$ sysctl kern.argmax
kern.argmax: 262144
```

This value includes space needed for the environment. It's probably a bad idea to pass blobs directly in the arguments.

You should pass the URLs and read the contents of the files in the process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to avoid putting fake resources in a bundle or downloading them over the network while testing on a real device. I've ended up with "Run Script" to copy images when building for "Debug".